# qt5 eat all the white space I inserted

Tags: html, qt

I used QString to generate html and convert it to pdf by QTextDocument.
However, the white space can't take effect at all,only one left.

I have tried the method from google to replace the " " with specified asc value. Such as &nbsp &#160 &#8194 &#8195.

if I type them in html, It's OK.

if set html content in QString, it's not OK,   is directly displayed in html,but not white space.eg.

```
"<p>&nbsp</p>"
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Just, tried generic html to pdf example [available from Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/Exporting_a_document_to_PDF).

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <p>Words&nbsp;separated&nbsp;with&nbsp;non&nbsp;breakable&nbsp;space</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectitur adipisci elit.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Which renders like this in Chrome:

[image]

Then using simple html to pdf conversion via QTextDocument class:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QString>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFileDialog>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName((QWidget* )0, "Export PDF", QString(), "*.pdf");
    if (QFileInfo(fileName).suffix().isEmpty()) { fileName.append(".pdf"); }

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOutputFileName(fileName);

    QTextDocument doc;
    doc.setHtml("<h1>Hello, World!</h1><p>Words&nbsp;separated&nbsp;with&nbsp;non&nbsp;breakable&nbsp;space</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectitur adipisci elit.</p>");
    doc.setPageSize(printer.pageRect().size()); // This is necessary if you want to hide the page number
    doc.print(&printer);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Gives me an output pdf file which renders like this:
[image]

As I see no spaces were removed and everything as it should be.
Will this code snippet help you to achieve what you want?

Or can you supply your simple compilable example, so we can check what is wrong?